# Qual é o equivalente ao media queries do CSS em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

Quando quero aplicar determinado estilo de acordo com o tamanho da tela, eu costumo usar as media queries do CSS.

Exemplo:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

    .container {
       width:960px;
    }

}
```

Gostaria de saber se no Javascript existe algo similar a essas funcionalidades do CSS.

Comment: O `@media` serve para várias coisas, não só tamanhos do screen, logo a resposta existente esta errada, ou melhor só meio correta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [Window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) para isso. Veja o exemplo abaixo.

```js
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width:800px)").matches) {
  /* a viewport tem pelo menos 800 pixels de largura */
  console.log('a viewport tem pelo menos 800 pixels de largura')
} else {
  /* a viewport menos que 800 pixels de largura */
  console.log('a viewport menos que 800 pixels de largura')
}
```

> Sobre a media print, existia um bug no [Firefox em sua versão 13](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=774398).

Referências:

- [$(window).width() not the same as media query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19291873/4843158)
- [MDN - Window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)
- [MDN - MediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode verificar o tamanho da tela e fazer alterações com css, veja:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"Screen Width: " + screen.width;

//tamano da tela
var size = screen.width;


if(size < 3000){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "blue";
  }
```

```css
#demo{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Resolve o problema em casos do tamanho da tela, mas não resolve em casos de `@media print`, por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que não tenha uma solução equivalente em javascript, porém, existem meios para se chegar em resultados convenientes.

A primeira forma, seria a combinação do evento que detecta mudanças na largura da `window`, juntamente com uma verificação da largura desejada:

```js
window.onresize = function(event) {
  if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
    console.log("Largura da janela menor que 768 px");
  }
};
```

A segunda forma seria utilizando o método [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia), conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```js
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)").matches) {
  console.log("A viewport tem pelo menos 500 pixels de largura");
} else {
  console.log("A viewport tem menos que 500 pixels de largura");
}
```

E através desta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625718/how-to-use-javascript-conditionally-like-css3-media-queries-orientation) no **SOen**, descobri que existe um plugin com a proposta de fazer o equivalente ao media queries do CSS em javascript:

https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a solução recomendada seja adicionar um *event listener* ao `MediaQueryList` como explicado na página https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener

```js
var mql = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');

function screenTest(e) {
  if (e.matches) {
    /* the viewport is 600 pixels wide or less */
    para.textContent = 'This is a narrow screen — less than 600px wide.';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  } else {
    /* the viewport is more than than 600 pixels wide */
    para.textContent = 'This is a wide screen — more than 600px wide.';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
}

mql.addListener(screenTest);
```